# phpMyAdmin not showing all rows - wrong number of total records shown

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm showing all rows (825) in phpMyAdmin v4.3.2 for a mysql innodb table sorted by the default autoincrement primary key. When sorted ascending, I go to the last page but it stops at id = 1150 when it should be id = 1337. The last 200 or so records do not display. When sorted descending, the records correctly start at the last record.

Oddly, increasing the number of rows per page give more of the missing rows and if I set it to 250 rows per page, they will all be there.

Any ideas why the result set is truncated? It seems as if phpMyAdmin is miscalculating number of pages.

**UPDATE**
I upgraded to the latest version 4.5.0.2 and the problem persists.

**UPDATE2**
The query executed when entering the table is `SELECT * FROM gems`
The result: Showing rows 0 - 24 (825 total, Query took 0.0000 seconds.)

When I do the query `select count(*) from gems` the result returns 997. So the problem is clearly in the estimated number of records phpMyAdmin thinks is there.

Comment: Can you provide the query phpmyadmin is executing? You should see it on the very top.

Comment: @frlan - I've included it in **UPDATE2** in the post. I then took the next logical step and did a count() query and it showed the problem clearly lies in phpMyAdmin's estimating the number of rows. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @frlan - I've figured out the problem. Thanks for your comment. It prompted me to look further and further until I had found it.

Comment: @mseifert Help others, share the problem you've found and the way you solved it in an answer.

Comment: @RizkyFakkel - Yes. Your comment and my answer were posted really close together.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found that I had the following setting in my phpMyAdmin config file pasted from who know what previous performance fix I made.

```
$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 0
```

This disabled correcting InnoDB estimates. I commented out this line, and of course it took care of the problem

Comment: The current default value is `50000`. This means, the number of rows is not accurate for larger tables. The previous (before version 4.8.0) default was `500000`. You might consider raising the value, but might get performance problems. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCount

Answer (score 0):

Add an auto increment BIGINT column at the beginning of the table, set it to UNIQUE and blamo! Fixed-ish. It forces phpmyadmin to get a real count when adding the auto increment key. I don't think PHPmyadmin is meant for doubling as your programs data management. In other words, your own application will not have these restraints, phpmyadmin is meant for development of your database structures etc, not for managing your customers...

You should not ever edit your phpmyadmin config file.