# DISTINCT returning more results than the original table

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I'm using MySQL database.
I have a table with 3 columns
ID1, ID2, String
When i query

`SELECT * FROM TABLE` i get:

Showing rows 0 - 24 (682701 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.)

When I query:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE` i get:

Showing rows 0 - 24 (696008 total, Query took 0.0009 seconds.)

I know the DISTINCT should remove the duplicates from the results, but in this case it's returning more results that the original records in the table !!!

Any idea why this is happening ?

**Update:**

I realized what is the problem. 
The problem is with the source code used to generate the number of records in PHPmyAdmin. When I use `SELECT COUNT (*)` I get the correct number of records which is not 682701 .

Comment: What are the columns in the table (you dont usually do DISTINCT *) but also maybe more data was inserted between running the queries?

Comment: You are selecting all the columns * and since you are getting duplicates. Select just the relevant columns which are required and verify

Comment: I also tried with (SELECT DISTINCT ID1, ID2). But, also returning the same number of results and without DISTINCT returning less !

Comment: i have a feeling you are using PHPmyAdmin? Can you look in the source code how the string `Showing rows 0 - 24 (682701 total, Query took 0.0006 seconds.)` is generated?

Comment: What engine are you using? (InnoDB, MyISAM, etc.) What indexes if any do you have? (minimum reproducible sample)

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are right. PHPmyAdmin is the problem.
I tried to use
`SELECT COUNT(*)` and it returned the correct number of records.
So it's a bug in the source code of PHPmyAdmin

Comment: let me guess the total in PHPmyAdmin is a estimate from `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TABLE`  Editted "So it's a bug in the source code of PHPmyAdmin" never mind you never looking into the source it seams..

Comment: By the way you can offcource run those `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TABLE`  and `EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE` then you can see if you get the same values. as phpMyAdmin has given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin not showing all rows - wrong number of total records shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050954/phpmyadmin-not-showing-all-rows-wrong-number-of-total-records-shown)