# Weird SQL table query results - total rows not adding up

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Today I had to add a few thousand rows to a table in our mySQL DB. Before I added the rows, I added a column `dateAdded` to the table, with the default set to `current_timestamp()` (existing rows would have `NULL` for this column). I added the rows and then did some double checking. Here's what's weird:

1. if I browse the table in `phpMyAdmin`, it says `Showing rows 0 - 24 (190,022 total ...)`
2. if I search for entries where `dateAdded IS NULL`, I get 184,854 rows
3. if I search for entries where `dateAdded IS NOT NULL`, I get 6,779 rows. That's correct, that's how many I added today

Notice that if you add up the total rows from 2 and 3 you get **191,633** rows, but 1 claims there are only **190,022** rows.

I've never noticed this sort of thing before. Is it normal? Should I wipe the table and add everything back again from scratch or something?

Note that I exported the table to a CSV and opened in Excel, sure enough there are 191,633 rows

Comment: Note that it says "Showing rows **0** - 24" (emphasis: me) -- it's apparently starting to count from zero. So likely that's either a bug or a "feature" in phpMyAdmin. You can ignore it, try updating or simply use another client all together... I wouldn't wipe the database though. Unless a `SELECT count(*) FROM that_table` isn't equal to `SELECT count(*) FROM that_table WHERE dateadded IS NULL` plus `SELECT count(*) FROM that_table WHERE dateadded IS NOT NULL`. That are the numbers that must match, I mean what the DBMS gives you directly, not some more or less good client...

Comment: The phpmyadmin thingy is a performance feature, see e.g. [phpMyAdmin not showing all rows - wrong number of total records shown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33050954) and the documentation at [phpmyadmin - cfg - MaxExactCount](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy comes from phpMyAdmin using `SHOW TABLE STATUS` instead of `SELECT COUNT`.  This is a performance optimisation to avoid `SELECT COUNT` on large tables which will carry significant overhead in some cases.

phpMyAdmin has a [MaxExactCount](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_MaxExactCount) configuration setting for the threshold used to decide whether to use `SELECT COUNT` or `SHOW TABLE STATUS`

> For InnoDB tables, determines for how large tables phpMyAdmin should
> get the exact row count using SELECT COUNT. If the approximate row
> count as returned by SHOW TABLE STATUS is smaller than this value,
> SELECT COUNT will be used, otherwise the approximate count will be
> used.
>
> Changed in version 4.8.0: The default value was lowered to 50000 for
> performance reasons.
>
> Changed in version 4.2.6: The default value was changed to 500000.

In the MySQL manual, [SHOW TABLE STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html) description for `Rows` column says -

> The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the
> exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is
> an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40%
> to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate
> count.

You can read more about InnoDB and the table rows statistic at -

1. [15.23 InnoDB Restrictions and Limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions-limitations.html)
2. [12.20.1 Aggregate Function Descriptions - COUNT(*)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)